# Формы C# Посоветуйте литературу

Tags: c#, form

Посоветуйте литературу по Windows Form, мне нужно код написать, а я понятия не имею, что как делать!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: Дубликатом не является. Сообществу на заметку - в списке отсутствует литература по WinForms в общем вопросе.

Comment: @AlexKrass выделенных книг по WinForms практически не бывает. Но в любой книге "для новичков" обязательно есть раздел по WinForms. Если знаете какую-то книгу по WinForms - допишите ее в общий список.

Answer (score 0):

По WinForms для начинающих могу посоветовать Голощапов А. "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010".
Версия 2010, конечно, уже несколько устарела, но Windows Forms  за это время практически не претерпели изменений. Так что основы там в понятном для новичка виде почерпнёте. А, дальше документация (читайте MSDN) и статьи в интернете.